# Form validation in php getting Notice?

Tags: php, forms, validation

When I click the `submit` button from the form without entering any values, it displays the message `Please fill all the fields` and error for the query. But it also generates the following notice:

`Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\statistics\savecourseadminscores.php on line 31`

Is this normal?

saveITScores.php

```
 <?php

 define('DB_NAME','some');//false name
 define('DB_USER','some');//false name
 define('DB_PASSWORD','some');//false name
 define('DB_HOST','localhost');

 $connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

 if(!$connect){
      die('Could not connect:'.mysql_error());
 }

 $db_selected=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connect);

 if(!$db_selected){
   die('Can\'t use'.DB_NAME.':'.mysql_error());
 }

$value1=$_POST['s1'];
$value2=$_POST['s2'];
$value3=$_POST['year'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if($value1 && $value2 && $value3){
       $sql="INSERT INTO itservice(s1,s2,year)    VALUES('$value1','$value2','$value3')";
    }
    else{
       echo "Please fill all the fields.";
    }
}
  if(!mysql_query($sql)){
     die('Error:'.mysql_error());

  }

  mysql_close();

  ?>
```

saveForm.php

```
  <div id="form">

<form action="saveITScores.php" method="POST">
S1: <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="s1" size="5"> <br /><br/>
S2: <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="s2" size="5"> <br /><br/>
<b>Year:<b/>
<select name="year"> 
<option value="Choose">Please select..</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option> 
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option></select><br/><br/>

<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit">
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear"><br /><br/>
```

Comment: Can you state in your code at which line you seem that notice will generate. And please use mysqli_* or PDOinstead of mysql_* because it is officially deprecated noe.

Comment: `if(!mysql_query($sql)){` <- Look at this if statement and think about it, when you get the output: `Please fill all the fields` when and where the variable `$sql` gets defined

Comment: @ anant kumar singh At line 31 in `saveITScores.php` I get this `Notice`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $value1=$_POST['s1'];
    $value2=$_POST['s2'];
    $value3=$_POST['year'];

    if(!empty($value1) && !empty($value2) && !empty($value3))
    {
       $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `itservice`(`s1`,`s2`,`year`)VALUES('".$value1."','".$value2."','".$value3."')")or die(mysql_error());
    }
    else{
       echo "Please fill all the fields.";
    }
}

     ?>
```

Comment: 1. And what should OP do with this code? 2. That won't fix OP's problem!

Comment: @Rizier123 why not? just corrected the code!!

Comment: And what did you corrected? Why did you corrected it, what was wrong with OP's code?

Comment: @Vicky thanks a lot it works fine, I don't get the `notice` anymore.

Comment: @Rizier123 i think the  op's problem has solved!!

Comment: @Vicky Still I think an explanation for future SO visitors would be helpful.

Comment: ok u were talking about the explaination